# Make a Start page to my game Java

Tags: java, tetris

I've been working on a version of a Tetris game and I tried to make a start page. I figured working with 2 panels will do fine but once I press the button the game doesn't run. Here is a piece of the code, where I implemented the panels.
Any ideas what I did wrong and how I should have done it?

```
public class Tetris extends JFrame 
    {

        JLabel statusbar;
        private JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
        private JPanel panel2=new JPanel();
        public Tetris() 
        {

            setResizable(false);
            setSize(200, 400);
            setTitle("Tetris");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            statusbar = new JLabel(" 0");
            JButton startButton = new JButton("START");

            panel1.add(startButton);

            panel2.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            Board board = new Board(this);
            board.addKeyListener(new TAdapter(board));
            panel2.add(board);

            startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    add(panel2);
                    panel1.setVisible(false);

                }
            });

            add(panel1);
            //board.start();

       }
```

Comment: try using `getContentPane().add(panel);` after the button has been clicked put the panel2.

Comment: Does any error message appears in starting console?

Comment: It's still the same :(
No error.

Comment: You could opt for a `CardLayout` instead which is developed to switch between different panels

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'revalidate' to your event handler. It should help, I guess.

```
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        add(panel2);
        panel1.setVisible(false);
        revalidate();

 }
```

});

By the way, if you are not forced to use Swing, I would advice you to use a modern JavaFX. Swing is not being developed by Oracle anymore.